# Generating an absolute node URL from its node id

Tags: nodes

I think the question is self explanatory. I got a node ID and I need to create its absolute URL somehow. I can do this but (I think) this won't work every where in the site:

```
<a href="?q=node/node-id">Node Title</a>
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there a function that I can give the node id and returns me back the absolute path of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function:

```
$url = url("node/$nid");
```

Comment: It partially worked. I have written exactly what you wrote, but in my address bar it doesn't show the node id. I get this `?q=node/`

Comment: Ohh sorry! My bad. I mis calculated something. I fixed this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 16):

## Drupal 8

```php
$nid = 5;
// Or $nid = $node->id();
$node_title = 'Node Title'
// Or $node->getTitle();
```

Create absolute URL:

```php
// Will output http://example.com/path-to-my-node
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url_object = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], $options);
// In Twig use {{ url_object }}.
// In PHP (outside a render array) use $url_object->toString().
```

Create absolute link object (and inner span):

```php
// Will output <a href="http://example.com/path-to-my-node" class="this-class"><span>Node Title</span></a>
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE, 'attributes' => ['class' => 'this-class']];
$node_title = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('<span>' . $node_title . '</span>');
$link_object = \Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute($node_title, 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], $options);
// In Twig use {{ link_object }}.
// In PHP (outside a render array) use $link_object->toString().
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Drupal 8** you can use [toLink](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AtoLink/8.2.x) function if you already load the node to generate an absolute link.

```
$event = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($event_id);
if (!$event)
  return false;

// add ->toString() or other if needed
$abs_link = $event->toLink(NULL, 'canonical', ['absolute' => true]);
```

For example.

This solution use same principle that previous answers but its seems to me more practical if you need other info from this node or if the node is already loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
$link = l("Node Title", $nid);
print $link;
```

Above code, prints the following output:

> `<a href="/node/XXX">Node Title</a>`

If you want to get **absolute URL** as you stated in your question:

```
$link = l('Node Title', $nid, array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

which will generate the link like:

> `<a href="http://example.com/node/XXX">Node Title</a>`

Comment: Good answer BUT to be honest it doesn't really answers question as asked. Would be good if you could add some info why op actually wants to use something else than he wrote.

Answer (score 1):

## Drupal 7

You can get path alias using [drupal_get_path_alias()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)

it will return:

> An aliased path if one was found, or the original path if no alias was found.

This function will give you pretty path if it is created by admin or by `pathauto` module. After that you can use path alias to build absolute url.

There are many ways to do that, you can use [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) or [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) or you can even use dirtier approach and concatenate `global $base_url` to path alias which will give you just absolute url as a string and print it in whatever template you want.

using `drupal_get_path_alias`:

```
$path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias("node/{node_id}", $language_code);
```

## Drupal 8

There are not above functions in Drupal 8 but you can do same using `path.alias` service.

e.g.

```
$path_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($system_path, $langcode);
```

## More

Please check [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1853148) for more information on both versions

Comment: In d8, this will not generate an absolute url.

Answer (score 0):

### Drupal 9

```
$entity->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
```

Comment: The OP only has the `nid`, so it would be good to include the step for loading of the entity to this answer.

Answer (score -3):

## Drupal 9

Best practice is the [AliasManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path_alias%21src%21AliasManager.php/class/AliasManager/8.8.x) service: [path_alias.manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path_alias%21path_alias.services.yml/service/path_alias.manager/8.8.x)

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/' . $nid);
```