# Best way to get a full absolute url from a registered route?

Tags: routes

I'm working with a module supplied route, and need to hand it off to an api.  That means I need the domain and schema included.  I am not finding the right options in the URL class, so I have it stacked with a bunch of calls.  This doesn't look right, feels clunky, is there a better way?

```
Html::escape( \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() .  Url::fromRoute('my_module.route_callback')->toString() )
```

Naturally I have the Html and Url use lines in this file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating an absolute node URL from its node id](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184914/generating-an-absolute-node-url-from-its-node-id) (specifically the second answer)

Comment: Yes, it looks like adding the `'absolute' => TRUE` to an array as the $options argument would properly prepend the host and schema.  Thanks.